Old movie maybe 60's or earlier, group goes to save woman from evil inventor living on top of mountain
Hard to tell year, style was more like 50-60's but possibly colored movie. It's group of heroes (no armour, some hand weapons) with some kind of science doctor going to save woman from evil inventor living on a mountain. At one point they encounter trap which is electrified spider net.
I've seen it when I was 5 years old in mid 80's in Polish state tv, then again couple years later. No monsters or supernatural beasts. It's most probably in english and probably American. It had same feel as old Vernes/adventure movies. Sorry but lack of details is due to remembering little about it. The doctor/scientist character was dressed in dark/black suit and coat with top hat like from Polansky "Vampire hunters" but I might be mixing memories up.

If by Heroes, you mean KISS then it could be KISS Meets the Phantom of the Park (1978) www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWE4O08XCOo

No by heroes I mean adventurers or group of males on mission. This movie is most probably from 50's and technicolor. It's not swashbuckler or Persia/Asia. I'll try to go through whole list of 50's adventure movies and see if I can find anything.
